# Protractor + Java issues. (AngularJS)

Tags: java, angularjs, protractor

I wanted to install protractor in order to work with our AngularJS project.
Everything went OK till I ran the command:

```
webdriver-manager start
```

...and I got some errors:

```
seleniumProcess.pid: 5421
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
```

Then I understood that I was using the wrong version of java (1.6.0_65).
So Ive got the latest one (1.8)
and basically the problem was that on terminal it would show me the old version. but on my actual computer would show me the latest.

However I tried uninstalling java by running this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
```

and been getting this, no matter what I do.

```
sudo rm: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted
```

**Has anyone experienced the same thing?**

(Using OS X 'El Capitan' as my operating system)

Comment: Use the standard mechanism that your Linux distribution has for uninstalling software packages instead of trying to delete it manually.

Comment: is there a solution or not

Comment: @DavidHesabian just [change your default java version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version) or [uninstall java as recommended](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) **that's the solution**,

Comment: For El Captain, this answer fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34201991/1615594

Answer (score 2):

You are using a mac and the default version of Java on mac osx is still Java 6 (Apple stopped producing their own version of Java a number of years ago). So, you need to manually install a more recent version of Java from Oracle to get the latest version.

[Download the latest version of Java here.](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp) Then, run the downloaded `dmg` file and follow the instructions to complete the installation.

After installing Java 8, simply re-run `webdriver-manager start` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Following from your response Andrew, I didn't find that installation to work so I downloaded the JDK instead which did at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html