# Unsupported major.minor version on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, macos

Following the solutions online for Major Minor version of Java being incorrect on El Capitan, I saw several solutions which made you either disable rootless, which i didn't like the sound of, or just didn't work anymore in OS X El Capitan.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There isn't one. This is a self answer to possibly help others who have the same issue, since i spent several hours searching for the solution and have posted it below.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When trying to run `webdriver-manager start` on El Capitan, you may get an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
```

The recommended fix for this online is to change the symlink that Mac OS X has to Java, which you can find by running `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the terminal.

This is pointing to the incorrect folder, and the error is because the application was compiled with a higher version of JRE than the machine is running in the terminal.

You should go to Oracle, and download the latest JRE version (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)

After this has been installed, you will have Java 8 on your machine, but it will not update the terminal properly. If you run `java -version` in your terminal, you'll see `Java Version "1.6"`, you want this to say `Java Version "1.8"`. The previous way to do this was to change the symlink manually, however, since El Capitan, Apple have made certain folders unchangable even to admin users, with their Rootless install. This includes the /usr folder.

There are two ways to fix this, the first is dangerous, and what everyone else seems to recommend. The second, is safer, and what I am putting here.

If you go to your `System Preferences -> Java -> Java -> View... -> System` and copy the Path field.

It will look something similar to the following:

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`

We want most of this path, except the `/bin/java` on the end.

So your path should now be copied as:

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Run the following command in the terminal, replacing [PATH] with the path you have from above.

`export JAVA_HOME="[PATH]"`

and run that in the terminal.

Afterwards, run `java -version` again, and it should now say `Java Version "1.8"`

Now, `webdriver-manager start` should succeed.

Comment: This worked for me but I also need to add the `export JAVA_HOME="[PATH]"` to my .bash_profile. If not, each time I restarted the path reverted back to 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to ~/.bash_profile worked for me:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.8)"
```

You might have to restart your shell for these changes to reflect or just run:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```